# Error during FLAASH Atmospheric Correction

Tags: envi, flaash, liss-iv

I am trying to carry out Atmospheric Correction for LISS4 data using FLAASH. Since LISS4 is not available in the sensor list of ENVI, I have made the filter function file using the spectral builder tool from relative spectral response file. I have made the channel definition file using the metadata of the image. After running the tool, I get the error as "Illegal subscript range : DATA". I am not able to understand this error to rectify it. Is there an issue with the filter response file that I am using or the channel definition file that I am providing?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the error. I was getting it because the sequence of bands in my composite image was different from the sequence of bands in my filter function file. Changing the sequence of bands in the composite image according to the filter function file resolved the error.